# Javascript access outer object attribute from anonymous function

Tags: javascript

I have the following object:

```
var object = {
    attr1 : "hello",
    myFunc : function() {
        alert(this.attr1);     //This should alert "hello"        
    },
    initialize : function() {
        document.getElementById("myElem").addEventListener("click", function() {
            // How do I access attr1 from here?

            myFunc(); // Says myFunc is not defined.

        });
    }
}

object.initialize();
```

How do I access `myFunc` or `attr1` from inside of the anonymous function passed to addEventListener?

One way I can think of is this:

```
var object = {
    attr1 : "hello",
    myFunc : function() {
        alert(this.attr1);     //This should alert "hello"        
    },
    initialize : function() {

        myObject = this;

        document.getElementById("myElem").addEventListener("click", function() {
            // How do I access attr1 from here?
            alert(myObject.attr1);

            // calling myFunc
            myObject.myFunc();
        });
    }
}

object.initialize();
```

But is this a good solution?

Also, If I do this:

```
var object = {
    attr1 : "hello",
    myFunc : function() {
        alert(this.attr1);     //This should alert "hello"        
    },
    initialize : function() {

        myFunction = this.myFunc;

        document.getElementById("myElem").addEventListener("click", function() {
            // How do I access attr1 from here?
            alert(myObject.attr1);

            // calling myFunc
            myFunction();
        });
    }
}

object.initialize();
```

Then it alerts with "undefined". Which means `this.attr1` is undefined.
Why so?

Comment: Yes, that's a common solution, but you forgot to declare the variable `var myObject = this`

Comment: @dystroy can you show it in a new answer by editing my code?

Comment: While yours is a typical technique and a good solution, you can also make use the `bind()` function: `.addEventListener("click" function() {}.bind(this));`

Comment: Why not just `object.attr1` and `object.myFunc`?

Comment: You could also directly use object without declaring a new variable, like `object.myFunc()` or `object.attr1`

Comment: And what about the third code snippet? Why does it say "undefined" in that?

Comment: `myFunction = this.myFunc;` There is no need to make another copy of the function. Instead use your second approach where you referred `this` using myobject

Comment: @mohamedrias Why does that difference exist when I create another copy of the function?

Comment: Only that particular function you've copied to myFunction variable not the object associated with it. Now this will refer to the window object.

Comment: @AninditKarmakar updated that behaviour in my answer, you can check it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside your event handler function, `this` will always refer to the DOM element on which the event has been attached.

To access the object properties, you need to use the alternatives such as self/that.

```
 initialize : function() {

        var that = this;

        document.getElementById("myElem").addEventListener("click", function() {
            alert(that.attr1);

            that.myFunc();
        });
    }
```

In your solution, you have declared `myObject` globally as `var` is missing.

```js
var object = {
attr1 : "hello",
myFunc : function() {
    alert("Instance of window ? "+(this instanceof Window));
    alert(this.attr1);     //This should alert "hello"        
},
initialize : function() {

    myFunction = this.myFunc;

    document.getElementById("myElem").addEventListener("click", function() {
        // How do I access attr1 from here?
        alert(object.attr1);

        // calling myFunc
        myFunction();
    });
}
}

object.initialize();
```

```html
<div id="myElem">Click me</div>
```

Now as you can see in the alert, `this` refers to the window object. Because when you copy the function, its by value and not by reference. So only the function is copied and not underlying object. So now `this` will refer to the window object.

Comment: Be careful with `self` because in it may be a reserved (and readonly) keyword. (In some Gecko based browsers.)

Answer (score 1):

The solution you provided is exactly how I go about solving this issue, declare a variable and set its value to `this`, then use that to call other functions within your object.

```
otherFunc: function() {
  console.log('test');
},

myFunc: function() {
  var self = this;

  // do stuff

  // call other function
  self.otherFunc(); 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make it like this - > 
You do not need extra variables to make your code so obscure. :)

```js
var object = {
    attr1: "hello",
    myFunc: function () {
        alert(this.attr1); //This should alert "hello"        
    },
    initialize: function () {

        document.getElementById("myElem").addEventListener("click", function () {
            // How do I access attr1 from here?
            object.myFunc();
        });
    }
}

object.initialize();
```

Comment: Are there any side effects of this approach? Or the other approaches?

Comment: from what i see just readability is affected by the other approaches and there is more room for errors when you have extra variables, about the code, no from my experience.